# change php output buffer before flush

Tags: php

Is there anyway to change output buffer before flush it?
I tried this function ob_set_contents but it seems there is no such a function,
I have the following in my header.php file:

```
ob_start(null,0,PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);
```

I need to do such a following in end of my footer.php file:

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
$output=str_ireplace("<-BlogXmlLink->","/en/rss.xml",$output);
ob_set_contents($output);
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual regarding `ob_start` parameters. From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> output_callback
>
> > An optional output_callback function may be specified. This function takes a string as a parameter and should return a string. The function will be called when the output buffer is flushed (sent) or cleaned (with ob_flush(), ob_clean() or similar function) or when the output buffer is flushed to the browser at the end of the request. When output_callback is called, it will receive the contents of the output buffer as its parameter and is expected to return a new output buffer as a result, which will be sent to the browser. If the output_callback is not a callable function, this function will return FALSE. This is the callback signature:
> >
> > > string handler ( string $buffer [, int $phase ] )

So instead of null to your second argument put a function that performs:

```
function($output) { return str_ireplace("<-BlogXmlLink->","/en/rss.xml",$output); }
```